# select statement for session

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server

I am new to .net, i write the select statement for session as like

```
Session["RoleId"] = "select roleid from AdminLogin where username='" + txtUserName.Text + "'";
```

but i m getting error what is problem with this.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: What kind of error are you getting?

Comment: What error? Pleas paste it here.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really intend to store the select statement in the session variable, or you want to retrieve a value from a database instead? In the later case, you need to use a database access engine such as [ADO.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h43ks021.aspx) or [LINQ to SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb425822.aspx).

Comment: It seems to me that this is the problem. He does not try to store the result of a query in the session variable but the sql query itself.

Answer (score 0):

I'm betting he's getting an error because his single quotes aren't escaped.  It should be:

```
Session["RoleId"] = "select roleid from AdminLogin where username=\'" + txtUserName.Text + "\'";
```

However, it should be noted that Raghu probably wants to exec the thing.  Look at the SqlCommand class and related examples.